# react-native firebase, firesrore, when getdownloadURL, how data store?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to store url in getdownloadURL. and want to use it in render func.
but whatever I'm done, (as far as I know) the uri was empty. could you help me how??

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const { ID, TIME,STAR,PHOTO,UID,COMMENT } = doc.data();
            const ref = firebase.storage().ref(PHOTO);

            ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
              this.setState({ uri: url })
             });

           // console.log(PHOTO);
            todos.push({
              key: doc.id,
              doc, // DocumentSnapshot
              ID,
              TIME,
              STAR,
              uri,
              PHOTO,
              UID,
              COMMENT
            });


          });
          this.setState({ 
            todos

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the db call ref will take some time, Javascript will continue on with the code and run the todos.push({ [your variables] } before the db call is done, so the uri will be empty. Try making the function "async" and await the db calls and see if that works for you.

```
            const { ID, TIME,STAR,PHOTO,UID,COMMENT } = doc.data();
            const ref = firebase.storage().ref(PHOTO);

             await ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
              this.setState({ uri: url })
             });

           // console.log(PHOTO);
            todos.push({
              key: doc.id,
              doc, // DocumentSnapshot
              ID,
              TIME,
              STAR,
              uri,
              PHOTO,
              UID,
              COMMENT
            });


          });
          this.setState({ 
            todos

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by myself.
the solution was pushing array in getdownloadURL and setstate as well.
the code is here

```
 ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => { // have a img
          // this.setState({ uri: url });
          todos.push({
            key: doc.id,
            doc, // DocumentSnapshot
            ID,
            TIME,
            STAR,
            uri : url,
            PHOTO,
            UID,
            COMMENT
          });
            this.setState({ 
              todos  
            });
```